# Regular Expression dot and comma issue

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this piece of code:

```
if(calcValue.search('[^0-9\*\+\-\/]') > -1) {
    jQuery('.output-field').text('Error: you can use only numbers and "+", "*", "-", "/" symbols');
  }
```

And this regular expression:

```
[^0-9\*\+\-\/]
```

must exclude all the symbols, except 0-9 digits and symbols: +, -, * and / but somehow it doesn't exclude dots and commas. How to exclude dots and commas too?

You can also check the code [here](https://codepen.io/fox_hover/pen/c70d5fa5e09b52e9ab8bf18841c9ce85):  there will be error message if you put in the input anything except numbers, allowed symbols and for unknown reasons dots and commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `String.prototype.search` incorrectly. It expects a regex - either a `/regex literal/` or a `new RegExp` object - but you are giving it a string.

Per the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search), the passed non-regex is implicitly converted to one using `new RegExp(arg)`.

You are passing in the string literal `'[^0-9\*\+\-\/]'`, which becomes the string `[^0-9*+-/]`. This is then implicitly passed as `new RegExp('[^0-9*+-/]')` and the resulting character class includes `+-/`, which expands to `+,-./` and this is where the comma and dot are allowed in.

I have two pieces of advice here.

The first, and most obvious, is to always pass the expected data type. In this case, a regex.

The second is to be more prudent with your escapes. They can be finicky at the best of times and there are many traps to avoid - especially when parsing happens twice (once for the string, once for the regex). Quantifiers do not need to be escaped inside a character class, and the `/` delimiter doesn't need escaping except if you're using a `/regex literal/`. Furthermore, the `-` range thing doesn't need escaping if it is the first or last character in the character class.

Consequently, my proposed fix is:

```
if( calcValue.search(new RegExp('[^0-9/*+-]')) > -1)
```

Comment: `which expands to +,-./` ... this is a bit of a rabbit.  Can you comment on how comma and dot end up in the character class?  It would seem to me that they are being allowed because certain types of numbers may have commas and decimal points.  But I can't prove this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Open up Character Map and you'll see that, between `+` and `/`, the symbols `,` `-` and `.` can be found. Nothing mysterious about it, it's just ASCII ;)

Comment: So coincidentally dot and comma alone got pulled in.  This would be a great interview question for someone.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Maybe, but only if Google is allowed. I wouldn't expect anyone to just know this.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass `search` a string as you do, but the `-` in your regular expression works as a range (the escapes are resolved in the string literal, so they make no difference for the regular expression):

```
[^0-9*+-/]
```

So your class forbids  `0` to `9`, `*`, `+` to `/`,  and that last range includes a dot and comma (and also the hyphen). So you should move the hyphen to the last position:

```
[^0-9*+/-]
```

Or, you should double escape the hyphen (once for the string literal, and again for the regular expression):

```
'[^0-9*+\\-/]'
```

Comment: Here is a [demo](http://rextester.com/QFWY96398) showing that this answer is correct.  The problem all along was that two of the symbols formed an unexpected character range.

Comment: Moving the hyphen to the last position helped my case